# Regular expression to replace in the middle of a string

Tags: regex, postgresql

For instance i have this string:

```
"blah blach &deg blah &deg;k as &deg "&deg""
```

What i want to do is to replace the &deg in the string above if there is no ';' after the &deg

I am using the following in postgresql

```
select regexp_replace('blah blach &deg blah &deg;k as &deg "&deg"', '\&deg[^;]', '\&;' ,'g' );
```

but i am getting this output

```
"blah blach &deg ;blah &deg;k as &deg ;"&deg";"
```

i want

```
"blah blach &deg; blah &deg;k as &deg; "&deg;""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your replace you're taking the literal string (the `\&` in the replacement parameter) that was matched and adding a semi-colon. The regex you've wrote grabs the `&deg` plus the next character that does not match a semi-colon, which works for matching, but not replacing/adding.

The easiest solution is to use groups to separate the `&deg` from the next matching character. Then use back-references to add the semicolon in the right place.

So using the following regex:

```
(\&deg)([^;])
```

Notice that `&deg` is group 1 and the next character will be group 2. You can now add the semi-colon directly after the `&deg` by using `\1;\2`

**Example**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('blah blach &deg blah &deg;k as &deg "&deg"','(\&deg)([^;])','\1;\2', 'g')
```

**Output**

```
blah blach &deg; blah &deg;k as &deg; "&deg;"
```